# Why does removing "Main nib file base name from Info.plist" prevent application execution?

Tags: swift, macos, xib

I've deleted my XIB file, removed it from the Info.plist, and In my AppDelegate I have this code. EDIT: It turns out that removing the Main nib file base name from Info.plist causes my application to not run?

I get this error:

```
Failed to connect (colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to 
(NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
```

I've deleted my XIB file on purpose, but why does it prevent execution of the program?

Comment: Hi, please do NOT edit the question to the totally different one. Open a new, separate question next time if you want.

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't answerable as it used to be, because the actual problem was me removing the XIB. Should I re-edit to add the original code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. It turns out that in the MainMenu.xib the AppDelegate object is attached as the application's delegate. Without the XIB the application can't send messages to it's delegate.

So I created my own main.swift file and in there I did this:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication()
let delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate = delegate
```

Then I was able to normally execute the app without any errors.